# How to tell if anything is selected in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, selection

I'm trying to determine with Javascript if anything is selected within the CKEditor. I wish there was a bool like `editor.hasSelection()`. I started out using `editor.getSelection().getSelectedText() === ""`, but if an element with no "text" is selected (like an img) then that will be a blank string, giving me a false negative. I also looked into `editor.getSelection().getSelectedElement()`, but that gives null if more than one element is selected.

Is there anything that does this that I'm not seeing in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me as though there is nothing in the CKEditor selection API to do this directly. However, I think the following will do it, although I agree that it's a shame (and surprising) there is no equivalent of the [`isCollapsed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection/isCollapsed) property of the native browser `Selection` object.

This is untested but looks as though it will work:

```
function hasSelection(editor) {
    var sel = editor.getSelection();
    var ranges = sel.getRanges();
    for (var i = 0, len = ranges.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if (!ranges[i].collapsed) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Example:
alert( hasSelection(editor) );
```

Comment: @user1810125: Ah, sorry about the return value mix-up. The idea was right :)